# conversion of string to datetime format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a created a table that stores dates in the DATETIME format. Now i want to retrieve date from a web form and insert into the table.I would like to know how to convert a string to the DATETIME format on the client side and then insert into the table.The form contains a checkin and checkout date and has no time.

Thank You

Comment: What format do you want to convert **to** and **from**? What have you tried? Could you please add an example of what you need?

Comment: The date string that i retrieve is of the form "03/12/2012"(MM/DD/YYYY) and want to convert it to the datetime form which is 03-12-2012 00:00:00 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out javascript's [parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this with the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
var d = new Date();
var _day = d.getDay();
var _month = d.getMonth() + 1; //months are zero based
var _year = d.getFullYear();
//assuming you always want the time as 00:00:00?? 
var str = _day + "-" + _month  + "-" +  _year + " 00:00:00";

str is now : 03-12-2012 00:00:00
```

​See a more generic demo here (uses today's date):
http://jsfiddle.net/8fEvy/

See the [Date object reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: But isn't the variable "STR" still of type STRING?

Comment: yes? If you want a date object then just use the `d` variable, but you  will have to put a string into your database right? You can't put a javascript date object there.

Comment: @user1270739 you're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. [See how accepting works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Date.parse it only returns milliseconds not date object .